# How do you use Guzzle to iterate through several pages of a paginated API response?

Tags: php, api, guzzle

I'm attempting to consume a REST API using the PHP library Guzzle.

The API results are paginated by the server, meaning they only return 20 rows at a time.

Pages are navigated by sending a `current_page` parameter e.g. `current_page=2`.

A typical response might look like this:

```
// First page of results
// Notice the lack of the "current_page" attribute
{
    "items": [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...} // etc
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [],
        "page_size": 20
    },
    "total_count": 197
}

// Second page
// Notice the presence of the "current_page" attribute
{
    "items": [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...}
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [],
        "page_size": 20,
        "current_page": 2
    },
    "total_count": 197
}
```

Is there a way that Guzzle can automatically iterate through all pages of the response without me having to clutter up the code with a `for` loop and manually calculate the current page figures etc.?

Comment: No, guzzle does not work with any custom API, it's just tool for requests. But that can be easily implemented. `while (count($response['items']) == $response['search_criteria']['page_size'])`

Comment: @Justinas I had imagined Guzzle might have a more elegant way to automatically page, perhaps given a reference to the required field names or something. Your particular example wouldn't work if your `total_count` was equally divisible by `count($items)`. E.g. 200 results / page size 20. It would loop forever.

Comment: Trust me, final page will return either 0 or <= than 20 results. That's how I am doing pagination: 200 items, 20 per page, 10 pages, 11th page will be empty

Comment: there is no protocol that apis have to list the pagination pages to a particular way so how do you imagine a library would know how the current api you are using is performing pagination, there are several ways in which a api response performs pagination each having their own key names